# RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc:349 input->dims->data[3] != filter->dims->data[3] (64 != 1)Node number 13 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Hello I am using semantic segmentation model. The model is subclass custom model. The model has also custom training loops. The model has been trained on cityscapes dataset and saved successfully. On the validation set the saved model also showed better accuracy I also convert it into tflite version. But when I tried for inference of tflite model it shows the above mentioned error in allocating tensors. I tried different things to remove that error.

1. First the model was trained on multiple gpu then I also trained it on single gpu but showed same error in both cases.
2. I tried using different batch sizes as some suggested that it showed error on high batch size. So I reduced the batch size the error was same.
3. I have also tried it using tf-nightly 2.7 and tf version 2.5 but it shows same error while allocation tensor.
   I have attached the colab link. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks
   https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v8SvJbMmjTyYVnRBeGwwCGSnRpkpR80p#scrollTo=L_PMowpPmaFx

Comment: Please file an issue on github and share the saved model and the command used for conversion.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues